# The total price goes below zero (reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, react-hooks, state

In this Burger app [github-repository](https://github.com/alimirzaeimajd/Umami-Burger) I made a burger program and my goal is to add and remove burger ingredients with two buttons and the total price is displayed, but by removing ingredients total price goes under zero This is what I tried and it didn't work:

`if (state.totalPrice[value] <= 0) { return state.totalPrice === 0; }`

and then I can't remove ingredients and get the following error:

> caught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
> at Object.removeIngredientsHandler [as removeIngredients]***

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRCjC.png)
how do i fix this?

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Burger from "./Burger/Burger";
import BurgerControls from "./BurgerControls/BurgerControls";
import BootstrapNavbar from "../ReactBootsrap/BootstrapNavbar";
export default function BurgerBuilder() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    ingredients: {
      meat: 1,
      salad: 1,
      cheese: 1,
      bacon: 1,
    },
    totalPrice: 0,
    INGREDIENT_PRICES: {
      salad: 0.25,
      cheese: 0.5,
      meat: 5,
      bacon: 1,
    },
    purchasable: false,
  });

  const addIngredientsHandler = (type) => {
    const oldCount = state.ingredients[type];
    const updatedCount = oldCount + 1;
    const updatedIngredients = {
      ...state.ingredients,
    };
    updatedIngredients[type] = updatedCount;
    const showPrice = state.INGREDIENT_PRICES[type];
    const oldPrice = state.totalPrice;
    const newPrice = oldPrice + showPrice;
    setState({
      ...state,
      ingredients: updatedIngredients,
      totalPrice: newPrice,
    });
  };
  const removeIngredientsHandler = (type, value) => {
    const oldCount = state.ingredients[type];
    if (oldCount < 0) {
      return;
    }
    const updatedCount = oldCount - 1;
    const updatedIngredients = {
      ...state.ingredients,
    };
    updatedIngredients[type] = updatedCount;
    const showPrice = state.INGREDIENT_PRICES[type];
    const oldPrice = state.totalPrice;
    const newPrice = oldPrice - showPrice;
    if (state.totalPrice[value] <= 0) {
      return state.totalPrice === 0;
    }
    setState({
      ...state,
      ingredients: updatedIngredients,
      totalPrice: newPrice,
    });
  };
  const disableButton = {
    ...state.ingredients,
  };
  for (let key in disableButton) {
    disableButton[key] = disableButton[key] <= 0;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <BootstrapNavbar />
      <Burger ingredients={state.ingredients} />
      <BurgerControls
        addIngredients={addIngredientsHandler}
        removeIngredients={removeIngredientsHandler}
        totalprice={state.totalPrice}
        disabled={disableButton}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You should investigate what's wrong with your calculation if the price ever goes below zero, not try to fix it after it has happened.

Comment: PS That error is telling you that you're trying to assign a new value to `removeIngredientsHandler` _somewhere_. So I would investigate that too.

Comment: state.totalPrice seems integer value. What are you trying to do with state.totalPrice[value]?

Comment: Yes, as @HeikoTheißen said, mathematically it should be zero when removing all items and SHOULD NOT go below zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should start with zero ingredients:

```
ingredients: {
    meat: 0,
    salad: 0,
    cheese: 0,
    bacon: 0,
}
```